# Match the lines that have a single slash before a special word

Tags: c#, regex

I have a number of lines in a similar format (actually, file paths). For example:

```
root/DATA/some/file.txt
root/DATA/another/file.txt
root/DATA/yet/another/file.exe
root/site/some/other/folder/before/DATA/file.xml
root/site/some/other/folder/DATA/file2.xml
```

I'd like to take only those that contain **a single slash before** `DATA`, that is the first 3 above should match, but the last 2 should not. NOTE: `root` is supposed to be a sequence of characters, excluding `/` and `\`.

I ended up with this regex, but it still matches all 5 samples:

```
[^/]*/data/.*
```

And I'm stuck here... How to instruct it to filter out the line in case `DATA` is not following explicitly after the first slash?

Comment: Have you made the Regex case insensitive?

Comment: @Oded, yep, but as you can see the problem was in regex itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should fix your problem:

```
^[^/]*/DATA/.*$
```

Comment: Indeed! As usual, one last little bit was missing...  Thanks!

Comment: The annoying part with ^ in regex is that it has two meanings. Makes it easy to overlook stuff...

Answer (score 0):

You should mark the start of the line:

```
^[^/]*/data/.*
```

Also, ensure that Regex is in multiline mode & case is ignored

Comment: It works, thanks! Actually, I check for match for every single line separately, hence no need to turn `multiline` on.

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^[^/]*/data/.*",
                        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have many options - like you could capture all DATA and later check how many elements '/' are before the text DATA (in for example the first group); you could check for a longer string etc. - exactly the thing which you have requested you may simulate and re-use using the code:

```
string type_1 = "" +
    "root/DATA/some/file.txt" + "\n" +
    "root/DATA/another/file.txt" + "\n" +
    "root/DATA/yet/another/file.exe" + "\n" +
    "root/site/some/other/folder/before/DATA/file.xml" + "\n" +
    "root/site/some/other/folder/DATA/file2.xml";

Console.WriteLine ("Start TEXT:");
Console.WriteLine (type_1);


Console.WriteLine ("Result TEXT:");
MatchCollection mat = Regex.Matches (type_1, "^[^/]*/DATA.*?$", RegexOptions.Compiled|RegexOptions.Multiline);
Console.WriteLine (mat.Count);
foreach (Match m in mat) {
    Console.WriteLine (m.ToString ());  
}
```

result of it's work is:

```
Start TEXT:
root/DATA/some/file.txt
root/DATA/another/file.txt
root/DATA/yet/another/file.exe
root/site/some/other/folder/before/DATA/file.xml
root/site/some/other/folder/DATA/file2.xml
Result TEXT:
3
root/DATA/some/file.txt
root/DATA/another/file.txt
root/DATA/yet/another/file.exe
```

it works by assuming that no '/' can be before the first 'DATA'.